# Runtime.exec() - pass file to open in linux, it finds app

Tags: java, runtime.exec

If my java app is running under Windows I can call Runtime.getRuntime().exec ("rundll32 SHELL32.DLL,ShellExec_RunDLL " + filename); and pass the file to be opened. Windows will then find the correct app and call it to open that file.

Is there a way to do this in linux? The file I am trying to open can be html, pdf, docx, ... (about 8 different extensions).

thanks - dave

Comment: Gnome has `gnome-open`. Kde has `kfmclient`. I don't know if there is a uniform way. Have you tried [java.awt.Desktop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [Desktop](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html)? Its purpose is to [open](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) files with the registered application.

Comment: Hi; I've never used the desktop - is there any downside to calling it and anything special I need to do to run an app? This is for a sample command line app we ship so we want it to run everywhere (which it looks like this does). ??? - thanks - dave